# optional nesting? What is this language feature called, and is it intended?

Tags: c#

I came across something interesting that I can't seem to find any more information on, or a proper name for.

I think most of us are aware that if you have multiple `using` blocks, you only need to include brackets after the last `using`:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(zipFilePath, FileMode.Open))
using (ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(fileStream))
{
    //stuff
}
```

However, goofing around I found that the following code also works, without brackets immediately following the `using`, piggybacking the `while`:

```
using (BinaryWriter br = new BinaryWriter(context.Response.OutputStream))
while (true)
{
    //stuff
}
```

Does anyone know the name of this language "feature" that allows code block merging?

Comment: I'll accept the highest-voted answer at around 12:00 Pacific time. Thanks for the great answers to a very basic question! I don't know how I missed something so basic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is intended. It is an idiom that C♯ inherits from C and C++. If you have a single statement enclosed in curly braces the braces are usually optional. Whether you use them or not is mostly an issue of style and readability. For nested `using` statements it's common to omit the braces for the outer layers.

#### Language grammar

In grammatical terms, a `using` block is followed by a *statement*. Usually this is a **block statement**, but it doesn't have to be.

There are a variety of kinds of statements. There are *expression statements* like `a = b;`. There are *iteration statements* like `while (boolean-expression) { ... }`. Here the entire `while` loop counts as a single statement. And there are *block statements*, which consist of one or more *statements* enclosed in curly braces.

See the C# Language Specification, Appendix C. Grammar, [§C.2.5 Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for a formal specification of *statements*:

> *statement:
>
>       labeled-statement
>
>       declaration-statement
>
>       embedded-statement
>
>   embedded-statement:
>
>       **block**
>
>       empty-statement
>
>       expression-statement
>
>       selection-statement
>
>       iteration-statement
>
>       jump-statement
>
>       try-statement
>
>       checked-statement
>
>       unchecked-statement
>
>       lock-statement
>
>       using-statement
>
>   block:*
>
>       `{`   *statement-list<sub>opt</sub>*   `}`

Usually the curly braces around statements can be omitted if you have a single statement. These are equivalent:

```
if (condition) statement;
if (condition) { statement; }
```

As are these:

```
using (...)
using (...)
    statement;

using (...)
using (...)
{
    statement;
}

using (...)
{
    using (...)
    {
        statement;
    }
}
```

#### Sometimes required

There are exceptions where curly braces are required. Method bodies must always have curly braces. It is baked into the grammar.

> *method-body:
>
>       block*
>
>       `;`

Similarly, `try`/`catch`/`finally` clauses *must* have curly braces. Same thing for `checked` and `unchecked`. You can see this in the grammar. A catch clause is defined as "catch *block*" rather than "catch *statement*".

> *try-statement:*
>
>       `try`   *block   catch-clauses*
>
>       `try`   *block   finally-clause*
>
>       `try`   *block   catch-clauses   finally-clause
>
>   specific-catch-clause:*
>
>       `catch`   `(`   *class-type   identifier<sub>opt</sub>*  `)`   *block
>
>   general-catch-clause:*
>
>       `catch`   *block
>
>   finally-clause:*
>
>       `finally`   *block
>
>   checked-statement:*
>
>       `checked`   *block
>
>   unchecked-statement:*
>
>       `unchecked`   *block*

Why is this? The short answer is it eliminates ambiguities in the grammar. For an in-depth explanation, see [Eric Lippert's explanation of this inconsistency.](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/04/why-are-braces-required/)

Answer (score 3):

`{ }` creates a single block of code.  If you do not have them, then the next statement is the block that gets executed.  As such, what you are doing makes sense, since the `using` would apply to the `while`.

Comment: [Here](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/04/why-are-braces-required/) is an interesting exceptional case.

Comment: HA. Wow. I need more sleep. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[As described by Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/04/why-are-braces-required/) whenever you have an `if`/`else`/`for`/`while`/`using`/`foreach`/`do`/`case`/`switch`/ etc. expression, it is always followed by a single statement.  Using braces (`{  }`) is just a way of making everything inside of those braces one statement.  Anytime you naturally have just one statement there is rarely a need (outside of possible readability) to use the braces.  Now, the readability can be reason enough in most cases, but from the compiler's point of view, it just expects any valid statement.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is that of the curly bracket operator.  It creates a variable scope, among other uses.  They can be omitted, and the code block is simply the following line.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  foreach(blah in y)
    dosomething();
```

That's a feature of many c-like languages.

Answer (score 1):

Using is followed by a statement, a block is a statement. Thus, although usually you have a block after using, you can have a single statement, which is while in your example but then, while is followed bya block.

Nothing unusual.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like this "concept" is the same principle as what allows for the following:

```
if(somethingTrue)
    when(somethingTrue)
       if(somethingTrue)
           // some code to be executed
```

Ie, a single line "block" instead of several lines within brackets.

Answer (score 1):

> you only need to include brackets after the last using

There is no requirement that the last using have `{ }`.  Your example is just a special case of the more general ability to nest statements with or without using compound blocks `{ }`.